# python arrow shifting hours

Tags: python, python-3.x, datetime, python-arrow

I am trying to add (shift) 6 hours to an arrow object, but somehow it seems to replace it instead:

```
>>> import arrow
>>> print(arrow.utcnow(),arrow.utcnow().replace(hour=+6))
2017-04-19T18:29:16.217239+00:00 2017-04-19T06:29:16.217304+00:00
```

The [documentation](http://arrow.readthedocs.io/en/latest/#replace-shift) gives me this example:

```
arw.replace(weeks=+3)
```

Why is it not working with hour? What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: `+6` is just 6. You're telling it to replace the hour with 6.

Answer (score 3):

You need to put an `s` behind `hour`:

```
>>> print(arrow.utcnow(),arrow.utcnow().replace(hours=+6))
2017-04-19T18:40:41.096311+00:00 2017-04-20T00:40:41.096371+00:00
```

The docs are a bit hasty in their example, but you could deduce it (weeks vs week)

> Or, get one with attributes shifted forward or backward:
>
> ```
> >>> arw.replace(weeks=+3)
> <Arrow [2013-06-02T03:29:35.334214+00:00]>
> ```

(from the docs)

`3` and `+3` parse to exactly the same (a positive value of 3), so the plus sign is not the part that makes the shift. It is only the difference between `week` and `weeks`.

In newer versions you can use `.shift(hours=+6)` to avoid being confused, as found in the [API docs](http://arrow.readthedocs.io/en/latest/#arrow.arrow.Arrow.shift).

Comment: Wow, that's a really confusing interface (especially since `+6` is still just 6 - the `+` doesn't do anything - but the user's guide doesn't explain anything and makes it seem like the `+` is important).

Comment: According to the [API guide](http://arrow.readthedocs.io/en/latest/#arrow.arrow.Arrow.replace), the use of plural names for relative shifts is deprecated.

Comment: so, `replace(hours=6)` actually does not replace anything, but just adds 6 to the hours? that's super confusing.

Comment: @user2357112 ah that makes more sense to use `.shift(hours=+6)` unfortunately this is not yet available in my standard ubuntu package, maybe through pip though..